# Do I need to recycle BitmapDrawable

Tags: android

According to http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is
>   recommended. If you're displaying large amounts of bitmap data in your
>   app, you're likely to run into OutOfMemoryError errors. The recycle()
>   method allows an app to reclaim memory as soon as possible.

I was wondering, for `BitmapDrawable`, do I need to perform cleanup like

`bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle()`

if it is no longer needed?

Comment: You will get OOM crashs at random places and the stack will make no sense. Debugging will be a nightmare, you will have to run heap tests between scenarios to figure out where the memory build up is happening. You will need about 3 days of debugging and 2 days of fixing and testing. DONT remove it. If its there, its there for a reason.

Comment: Why is nobody answering your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to recycle bitmaps when not in use. You can load bimaps in onResume() and recycle the same in onPause().

So to reduce memory consumption and avoid memory leaks it is better to recycle bitmaps when not in use.

Also have a look at the Memory Management talk in the link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Edit:

A quote form the link you posted. (You can check under the heading Manage Memory on Android 2.3.3 and Lower)

**On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, using recycle() is recommended**.

Starting with HoneyComB bitmaps are stored on HEAP instead of their native bitmap heap.

Android 3.0 (API Level 11) introduces the BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap field. If this option is set, decode methods that take the Options object will attempt to reuse an existing bitmap when loading content. This means that the bitmap's memory is reused, resulting in improved performance, and removing both memory allocation and de-allocation

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: What I mean is, for BitmapDrawable, is this the correct way to perform recycle? - bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle()

Comment: are you getting any exceptions or error while doing the same. If not recycling should not be a problem

Comment: Nope. The code is being executed ok. Just that, I'm not sure how can I know, whether the previous allocated memory, is properly being de-allocated.

Comment: If you have memory leaks you can use MAT Analyzer. the dalvik vurtual machine does garbage collection. You can check logcat if your heap size is growing or not.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) tells you

> This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the
>   normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more
>   references to this bitmap.

So I'll go with: no, you don't need to call it. Free your bitmap resources, though, by clearing up the references you have.

The link you added pretty much tells you why it might have helped before and after:

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for
>   a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap
>   itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap. The pixel data in native
>   memory is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an
>   application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash. As of
>   Android 3.0 (API Level 11), the pixel data is stored on the Dalvik
>   heap along with the associated bitmap.

Comment: It really depends on how much data you have.  If you have lots of bitmaps, especially screen-sized bitmaps with double buffering, you absolutely need to call recycle or will run OOM.  If you just have a bunch of icons, you're probably ok without it.  If you're dynamically generating bitmaps, I'd say always call recycle to be on the safe side.

Comment: @GabeSechan Actually, I do use it myself. But like I put in my amended answer, there's a reason why the use before and including API level 10 was highly recommended and why it's not as necessary afterwards.

Comment: I find it just as necessary in level 10+, possibly more so.  I have more crashes due to OOM now when manipulating large files (like 10 MB pdfs), because images that previously didn't count against the limited dalvik heap now do.

Comment: @DigCamara can you quote the reason for the same why  it's not as necessary for api level 10 and above?

Comment: @Raghunandan I keep quoting the link> Android 2.3 adds concurrent garbage collection, which means that the memory is reclaimed soon after a bitmap is no longer referenced. < That and the placement of the bitmap mean that as soon as there are no references, the memory should get garbage collected, whether or not you make the recycle call

Comment: @GabeSechan they always counted against the heap. Moving the pinned memory into the heap made their effect easier to see and it also allowed the GC to collect bitmap memory without waiting for a finalizer to run.